# Django REST Framework class-based views inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django REST Framework and I found myself in the following situation: I have two `APIView`s that are identical to one another except for the ordering of the objects they return:

```
# Route: "/new"
class NewView(APIView):
    """
    Returns JSON or HTML representations of "new" definitions.
    """
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    def get(self, request):

        # Queryset
        definitions = Definition.objects.filter(language=get_language())
        definitions = definitions.order_by("-pub_date")

        # HTML
        if request.accepted_renderer.format == "html":
            context = {}
            context["definitions"] = definitions
            context["tags"] = get_tags(definitions)
            return Response(context, template_name="dictionary/index.html")

        # JSON
        serializer = DefinitionSerializer(definitions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

# Route: "/random"
class RandomView(APIView):
    """
    Returns JSON or HTML representations of "random" definitions.
    """
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    def get(self, request):

        # Queryset
        definitions = Definition.objects.filter(language=get_language())
        definitions = definitions.order_by("?")

        # HTML
        if request.accepted_renderer.format == "html":
            context = {}
            context["definitions"] = definitions
            context["tags"] = get_tags(definitions)
            return Response(context, template_name="dictionary/index.html")

        # JSON
        serializer = DefinitionSerializer(definitions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

As you can see, the only line that changes between these two views is the one that orders the `Definition` objects. **How can I create a parent view to contain the shared code and a child view to sort objects?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class BaseView(APIView):
    order_field = None
    """
    Returns JSON or HTML representations of "new" definitions.
    """
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    def get(self, request):

        # Queryset
        definitions = Definition.objects.filter(language=get_language())
        definitions = definitions.order_by(self.order_field)

        # HTML
        if request.accepted_renderer.format == "html":
            context = {}
            context["definitions"] = definitions
            context["tags"] = get_tags(definitions)
            return Response(context, template_name="dictionary/index.html")

        # JSON
        serializer = DefinitionSerializer(definitions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class RandomView(BaseView):
    order_field = "?"


class NewView(BaseView):
    order_field = "-pub_date"
```